# Oscillator without active components

Tags: oscillator, components

Is it possible to construct an oscillator using only passive components, including R, L, C, and transformers? No semiconductors or vacuum tubes, etc. Batteries are allowed.

Comment: Do you expect it to continue to oscillate?

Comment: This seems very improbable.  Not sure how you would excite the circuit. Even if you could start an oscillating system, you would quickly lose energy in any resistive components and would have no means of injecting energy back into the system.

Comment: A LC resonator will lose energy from parasitic R + any EM radiated from the system.  You could probably make a parlor-trick circuit using the negative differential resistance characteristic of a passive component driven at an extreme condition (e.g. arcing as in a Tesla coil) but that's stretching the definition a bit.  Ditto self-heated thermal switches.

Comment: Would you count Faraday’s mercury motor? It was the first electric motor, dating from 1821. Just a battery, mercury, wire and you get rotation.

Comment: Are relays allowed? How about an electrical device providing energy to keep a mechanical pendulum oscillating?

Comment: https://teslauniverse.com/nikola-tesla/articles/electrical-oscillators

Answer (score 3):

You can use a mechanical vibrator circuit as done in the vacuum tube days for power inverters to generate B+ voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDl55F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A relaxation oscillator can also be made with a neon bulb.

Answer (score 2):

For an electrical oscillator, you need a component (components) that have *power* gain. This means e.g. a transformer (alone) isn't sufficient because it has voltage gain, but not power gain.

Passive components can't have power gain directly, but clearly a DC motor 'oscillates' using a DC power source (battery), wires and magnets. However note that it also has switches (commutator) which do give a power gain through mechanical motion. Following the same logic, a relay can be made oscillate (make the contacts short the coil when activated...).

It is possible to make a passive circuit oscillate if it has a negative resistance characteristic. This can be used to convert DC power into AC power (which is the oscillation). A tunnel diode oscillator is an example of that [Tunnel Diode Oscillator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sinusoidal_oscillators/sinusoidal_tunnel_diode_oscillator.htm#:%7E:text=The%20oscillator%20circuit%20that%20is,Esaki%20diode%2C%20after%20its%20inventor.).

Along the same lines, a parametric oscillator has no 'active' (e.g. 3-terminal) devices (transistors), but can oscillate - [Parametric Oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_oscillator). A laser is a related example.

Answer (score 1):

Every passive resonant RLC is lossy and eventually  decays. But very high Q series resonant circuits be made with occasional pulses (active) to sustain  Oscillations.

Series Q is defined as the characteristic impedance of the lumped elements \$Q=\dfrac{Z_0}{R_S}=\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}*\dfrac{1}{R_S}\$.

Yet all wires have inductance ~ 0.8 +/xx% nH/mm and resistance, so it would need to be very thick wire and in a precise helix with ppm tolerances to achieve a Q >> 1000, otherwise Q=100 is a practical limit in a parallel resonance Q=Zo/R or inject a pulse in a series short loop.

Interwinding gap/thickness can be varied to alter Cp Or a very high Q NP0 cap. added in parallel.  The decay time can be measured as T=L/R for series. Or T=RC for high impedance parallel.

In short, the answer is not really unless activated by some other energy like gamma pulses or a magnetic field of pulses coupled to the coil. But the latter still needs an active source of energy.

Answer (score 0):

Early “candlestick” telephones oscillated when the carbon microphone was brought close to the earphone.